# How to create a Pattern for a date using a Scanner?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner

I have a `.csv` file with lines like:

```
30-11-2013 ;30-11-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;2800.0 ;2800.0
31-12-2013 ;31-12-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;3000.0 ;3000.0
02-01-2014 ;02-01-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3300.0 ;3300.0
02-01-2014 ;02-02-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3600.0 ;3600.0
03-01-2014 ;03-01-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3900.0 ;3900.0
```

I have a `Scanner` running those line, and I need to create a `while(scanner.hasNext(somePattern))` that returns `true` if the next line start with a date like `30-11-2013`.

What should `somePattern` be?

P.S. in the cycle, the scanner runs all the lines so I need to know that the next token starts with a date.

Comment: This does not look like a CSV to me - more like a SCSV (if there were such a thing as semicolon separated value file).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Don't matter is it a .csv or .scsv or .txt. The question is how to create a pattern for `xx-xx-xxxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern is class which handles regular expressions. So in your case you want to check if data after start of line has `two digits` `-` `two digits` `-` `four digits`. Regex which represents such situation can look like

```
^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}
```

where `^` represents start of line, `\d` represents single digit and `{x}` describe how many times element before it should appear.

So you can try using following Pattern (instances of Pattern class are created via `compile` method which beside regex can accept combination of flags which can slightly change default regex behaviour).

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

I added `MULTILINE` flag to let `^` represent start of each line, not just start of entire data which would be its default meaning.

DEMO

```
String input = 
        "30-11-2013 ;30-11-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;2800.0 ;2800.0\r\n"
        + "31-12-2013 ;31-12-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;3000.0 ;3000.0\r\n"
        + "02-01-2014 ;02-01-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3300.0 ;3300.0\r\n"
        + "x02-01-2014 ;02-02-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3600.0 ;3600.0\r\n"
        + "03-01-2014 ;03-01-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3900.0 ;3900.0";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}",
        Pattern.MULTILINE);
while (scanner.hasNext(pattern)) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Output:

```
30-11-2013 ;30-11-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;2800.0 ;2800.0
31-12-2013 ;31-12-2013 ;SUMMARY ;0.0 ;200.0 ;3000.0 ;3000.0
02-01-2014 ;02-01-2014 ;TRANSF ;0.0 ;300.0 ;3300.0 ;3300.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file is so regularly formatted, all you need is a simple list of character patterns representing each part of your string:

```
^\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d ;\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d ;SUMMARY ;\d+[.]\d+ ;\d+[.]\d+ ;\d+[.]\d+ ;\d+[.]\d+$
```

Of course you need to escape the slashes to put this expression in a Java string.

The [documentation for the Pattern class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) provides a great cheat-sheet of the pattern elements. `\d` matches a single digit; `\d+` matches one or more digits.

Comment: What you mean with escaping the slashes? Sorry, im new in Java.

Comment: @yarokas Java strings use backslash to write special characters. For a slash itself you need to write two slashes, like this: `"^\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d ;"` and so on.